# Oracle tablespace/data file issue - ORA-00376

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tablespace, data-files

Many months ago while shrinking table spaces I mistakenly deleted a table space with out taking backup. There were many indexes which belonged to tables which are a part of that table space.

I never had any problems while inserting or deleting records from tables which belonged to that specific tablespace. But from yesterday I observed that data isn't inserting into many tables due to indexes on it which are giving me error that unique index violated which belong to that specific table space.

Since this morning, I am receiving this error which is caused by a file which was deleted by me:

```
ORA-00376: file 663 cannot be read at this time
ORA-01110: data file 663: '/oradata/db3/pm/pm4h_db_dat_w_150316_02.dbf'"
```

How can I overcome this error?

I also now tried to recover the file which gives me this error:

```
SQL> recover datafile '/oradata/db3/pm/pm4h_db_dat_w_150316_00.dbf';
ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
ORA-01122: database file 661 failed verification check
ORA-01110: data file 661: '/oradata/db3/pm/pm4h_db_dat_w_150316_00.dbf'
ORA-01207: file is more recent than control file - old control file"
```

Comment: Please post your error as text, not an image. I don't quite understand what you did, or what the relevance of the unique index violation is. What exactly did you drop or delete? What do you have in the dba_tablespaces and dba_datafiles views? Does the file in the error exist, and can you see its directory and other files in there?.I'm wondering if you might have an unrelated disk (or SAN etc.) problem this morning,  but there isn't much to go on.

Comment: @AlexPoole I have edited the question. included the text form of the error. I dropped all the indexes which belongs to those faulty files. so make the data available.

Comment: @AlexPoole but i mistakenly deleted some files which shrinking the tablespace. due to which all of this happening. but i am wondering why after around 10 months this started to appear ? before it was okay even the files were deleted

Comment: See this link [https://www.pythian.com/blog/how-to-recover-deleted-oracle-datafiles-with-no-downtime/